# MySQL conditional grouping?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have SQL code that returns total balance for customer id:35

```
SELECT
    d.customer_id,
    SUM( IF(d.side="K" AND d.type<>"employee-cash-out", -ABS(d.total), ABS(d.total)) ) AS total,
    d.currency_id
FROM dea_documents d
WHERE d.customer_id=35 OR d.parent_customer_id=35
GROUP BY d.currency_id
ORDER BY d.customer_id, d.document_date
```

Example result:

```
customer_id | total       | currency_id
35          | 8.08        | USD
35          | 1.52        | EUR
```

The problem is that documents must be grouped by (d.customer_id or d.parent_customer_id).

Is it possible to have a SELECT for all the customers grouped?:

```
customer_id | total       | currency_id
13          | 139749.54   | USD
13          | 4283.62     | EUR
17          | 60.00       | USD
17          | -11.57      | EUR
29          | 13498.67    | USD
29          | -347.29     | EUR
```

UPDATE:

I ended up with this code

```
SELECT
    d2.customer_id, 
    SUM( d2.amount ) AS total,
    d2.currency_id
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            IF(parent_customer_id<>"", parent_customer_id, customer_id) AS customer_id,
            currency_id,
            IF(d.side="K" AND d.type<>"employee-cash-out", -ABS(d.total), ABS(d.total)) AS amount
        FROM dea_documents d
    ) d2
GROUP BY d2.customer_id, d2.currency_id
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Marked Barmar answer because it helped me here and it was the closest one :)

Comment: Should each document be added to both its own customer ID and its parent customer ID?

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot do a `GROUP BY d.customer_id, d.currency_id` ?

Comment: @Tim documents must be grouped by [d.customer_id or d.parent_customer_id]. Did you read the question :) ?

Comment: @Barmar it is not required

Comment: If it's not in both, how do you determine which group it should be in?

Comment: If I understand you question correctly: if parent_customer_id is not empty it should be in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `UNION` to get both the `customer_id` and `parent_customer_id` into the same column before grouping:

```
SELECT d.customer_id, 
        SUM( IF(d.side="K" AND d.type<>"employee-cash-out", -ABS(d.total), ABS(d.total)) ) AS total,
        d.currency_id
FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, side, total, currency_id
    FROM dea_documents
    UNION
    SELECT parent_customer_id as customer_id, side, total, currency_id
    FROM dea_documents) AS d
GROUP BY d.customer_id, d.currency_id
ORDER BY d.customer_id, d.currency_id
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution! At the moment it is returning strange amounts... I will test it more.

Comment: If you post the original table data and the desired results, I can try to figure out why it's producing strange results. Maybe you should answer the question I asked in the comment above, it might be relevant.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ is down at the moment. I will upload some data when it is accessible.